# Apache Cordova: Download images and use as icons

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a very specific use case. I want to download images from a server at runtime and use them in my Apache Cordova application as images (navigation icons, buttons, ...). It is a dynamic configuration of the application, which is configured on the server. However, since the app should work offline, I would like to download all the required images and use them in the offline scenario.

Comment: So what is your question? You say that you "have a very specific use case". If it's that specific, you should provide specific information but not just three short sentences.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to change app icons dynamically. Icons are set when building the app.